# What does the loggedin column of vBulletins session table mean?

Tags: session, vbulletin

In vBulletin 4.2 the `session` table has a column `loggedin`. Since VB doesn't seem to have a official database documentation, I want to know what exactly it means because the column it's a `SMALLINT` instead of simple boolean value.

My previous reverse engineering: **0** means not logged in. **1**  and **2** is used for logged in users, but I can't see what's the difference. I have both regular user session and admin panel sessions with `loggedin=2`.

Tried to get more information by running `grep` on vBulletins php files, <strike>without luck</strike> .

#### So my concrete questions are:

- What is the difference between sessions with 1 and 2?
- Are there more states than 0, 1 and 2?
- Do they even matter when vBulletin's code doesn't seem to use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that my filter to `*.php` files broke `greps` recursive scanning method. The correct command to scan *all* php files for `'loggedin'` (in quotes since vB use them this way on it's `$vbulletin->session` object) is:

```
grep -rn --include \*.php "'loggedin'" .
```

This gave a few results. Most interesting:

```
./includes/functions.php:7558:                  $vbulletin->session->set('loggedin', 2);
```

Opening `functions.php` we see the call and we can feel lucky that at least in the code vB developers to decide that a comment would be usefull:

```
if ($vbulletin->session->vars['loggedin'] == 1 AND !$vbulletin->session->created)
{
      # If loggedin = 1, this is out first page view after a login so change value to 2 to signify we are past the first page view
      # We do a DST update check if loggedin = 1
      $vbulletin->session->set('loggedin', 2);
      // ...
}
```

So we can say that 1/2 doesn't gave information about the type of session. It could be a regular user or also admin session. Altough `loggedin` indicates if the user already viewed some other pages or not, whyever vB devs need to devide this.